# New user owns old apps in Mac

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator, guest-account

I just created a second user in my computer so guests can use my Mac without the need of using my account. I did this through the GUI (Settings → Users → New User).

While trying to set up permissions and restrictions. I can see that this new user is shown as owner of some of the Applications in my Mac.

- Why is this happening?
- Should it be happening at all?
- Is this Unix related, or macOS related?

Comment: Which apps? And were they already installed before?

Comment: I do not have access right now, but just normal apps. (I can list them later on). Yes, they were installed before.

Comment: I'd be interested to know which apps. Are these OS-bundled apps, like Preview; or Mac App Store apps, or third-party apps that were downloaded from websites. Did they use an installer? I've added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Can you add some details about what you mean by "own"? Where are the applications stored, who exactly is the owner? Screenshots might help to explain things which are hard to describe.

Comment: Also your bounty description is a bit confusing: Creating new users should not change ownership of existing files/folders. So I'm not sure whether we chasing ghosts here.

Comment: @nohillside, that is the whole point of the question, I do not know why this is happening, but my background is neither mac, nor system management. I myself am seing ghosts.

Comment: @benwiggy, so as you list in your post, apps that changed owner are those I once dragged into the folder (as user Bob) and now when Alice created where ownd by Alice. I am still dubious as to how the system wanted/needed to change the ownership on new user creation tho... (being Bob my normal user, and Alice the one I created).

Comment: I too am dubious about how the system changed the ownership. ;-) Without more information, such as the UIDs of the users involved, a sample ls -la listing, and actual named apps, it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: I understand that you don't know, that's totally fine. But unless you provide the details people ask you about, we will have only a slime change of figuring out what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps that are dragged into the `/Applications` folder by a user will be owned by that user - e.g. the Unix *owner* attribute will be that of the user that did the dragging. Apps from the Mac App Store and apps that were delivered via an installer package tend to have `root` as their owner.

```
drwxrwxr-x@  13 root  admin    416 28 Nov  2012 Adobe Photoshop CS6
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel     96  8 Oct 12:31 Affinity Designer.app
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel     96  8 Oct 12:31 Affinity Photo.app
drwxr-xr-x    3 Ben   admin     96 31 Oct 13:03 Affinity Publisher.app
drwxr-xr-x@   3 root  wheel     96 23 Jul  2019 App Store.app
drwxr-xr-x    3 Ben   staff     96  3 Oct  2012 Art Directors Toolkit 5i.app
```

The apps here with owner "Ben" were downloaded and dragged into the `/Applications` folder. The root-owned apps are OS-bundled, from the Mac App Store, or installed via a .pkg.

The *group* varies, but is largely irrelevant.

**Should it be happening at all?**

No. Creating a new user account should not change the ownership of these apps.

**Is this Unix related, or macOS related?**

MacOS ***is*** Unix™. But yes, it's happening at the Unix/POSIX level of file attributes.

**Why is this happening?**

Without more information, this is unknown. 
The only reason I can think of relates to User ID numbers. Every user has a unique ID number. The first user created is number 501. Subsequent accounts will be numbered 502, 503, etc.

It may be that the original account used to move these apps to the `/Applications` folder was deleted, and the new user account has been given the same user ID number, thus inheriting its ownerships.

You can determine the UID of a user with `id -u <username>`.

As long as the app has the *read* and *execute* flags set for all users, then everyone can launch the app. The ownership only matters for deleting the app.

Comment: From my understanding that depends greatly on the app and where it stores its related files (under root home folder or under user home folder). Is not that I need it, I want know how to have finer control on permissions and restrictions in general on an account basis, and I see nowhere to change this easy through GUI. So what if I want to restrict access or hide for example Visual Code.app, or Chrome.app?

Comment: In unix I would usually do this through groups/users/owner permissions and passwd and shadow files, but there seems to be no such thing in mac.

Comment: Anything that an app stores in a user account should be specific to that user only. If an app itself is installed in a user account, then obviously it's only available to that user. 
You want to stop your wife from accessing certain apps? 
Mac IS Unix. Anything you can do in Unix you can do on a Mac. If you want to change the attributes so your wife is outside the group that can read the app, then you can do that. Or you could use MacOS's Parental Controls.

Comment: I can see your point. Thanks for the clarification. This does not answer my questions though.

Comment: What questions do you still have?

Answer (score -2):

Obviously, you should set up the new user so that it *can't* "manage your computer."

And I would go on to say that "the account which you use every day" should not be able to do that, either.

Nevertheless, users do not "own" applications.